# Buying a logo from a graphic designer: who owns the copyright?

Tags: logo, copyright, business

I am working with a graphic designer for a new logo.  They are offering the logo, but have said there will be parameters put in place to prevent me from editing the logo myself.

Is this commonplace in this industry?  I would prefer to be able to personally edit the font if I choose to, or change font color/placement.  Also, I'd like to change colors (as we have not yet chosen our colors).

I am pretty proficient in illustrator, and would prefer not to deal with the graphic designer again in the future if I don't need to.

Comment: Well yes. And no you really dont want to do what you say you do in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Just a personal comment. Do not underestimate a Grpahic Design Profession. Design is a LOOOOOOOT more than being "proficient in illustrator" https://www.google.com./search?q=really+bad+logo+design

Comment: @rafael I was being modest.. im a very good graphic designer.  In fact, after seeing this graphic designers work, I no longer want to go with them.  However, I'm willing to give him money for his time (he is a friend of my business partners), if i can use the work he did that I like (part of an icon)

Comment: Oh. Ok then. :o)

Comment: @Ricky It may be worth rewriting this question with out the modesty then. "I am a graphic designer, starting a new company in another area. My business partner suggested that we contract out our logo design to a friend of his -- who I thought was much more experienced than me -- thus allowing me to focus on the other parts of starting the new business. I am not satisfied with the results of the designer we contracted to (though I am willing to pay for his time). I would like to almost start the logo design again, keeping just a small part of his work. But ..." then continue into the question.

Comment: I disagree with the answer that was marked as correct. I'd wait and get more opinions before marking an answer.

Comment: @DA01 For logos often yes your given all rights but not allways. For example ive seen logo authors negotiate minimum times for showing logo as is before releasing it fully. Ive also seen logos contracted under marketting campign orders that didnt get treated as logos by the designers but rater titles in a flyer. So while i agree that logos should be contracted with all rights not all clients seem to realize the different nuances and are surprised theres a difference. So if you really want all rights you must specify to make sure. Otherwise theres a risk of misunderstanding.

Comment: @DA01 also its a bit tricky as the OP wants to do derivate work immediately

Comment: @joojaa yes, certainly not *always*.

Comment: If they want to protect it, it's not really buying, more like a lease. If you actually buy it, it's YOURS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For logo work, no, this is not common. A graphic designer understands that a company needs to own their visual identity outright including with that to modify it in the future as they see fit. As others have stated, it's not necessarily a *good idea* but it absolutely should be within your rights as the owner of said logo.

Comment: this made the most sense in my opinion.  Im glad to hear that it is not necessarily common place.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your contract, graphic designers charge different prices for different rights to their work. What you are asking for is full transfer of rights, including all intelectual and moral rights.

This is the sort of thing you need to have negotiated before you begin the job because it affects how the job is executed and whether or not the designer will bother to take the job or not.

In essence this boils down to a few things:

- Why would you want to even begin doing that
- You're essentially asking the designer to dissasociate themselves from the design. The designer can no longer use you as a reference. This may be more than enough for a designer not to bother as you do not grow his chances of getting new work.
- In fact you're not buying a logo you're buying either a template system for a family of logos or your buying a tutorial into logo design and should be charged appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Much depends on the contract and the price paid for the work product/rights.

Our studio typically retains the copyrights, the client can register a trademark.  Something we openly recommend.

The reasons vary but the reality is when a client or anyone else (say for example a printer) modifies the work/product artistic and legal problems develop.

Comment: To be clear, your firm owns the *copyright* to corporate identities of companies?

Answer (score 0):

It is common for many designers to do this. If you only paid a couple hundred dollars or less, you might only be paying for the right to use their design instead of for the files themselves. Check your design contract if you have one to see what it says.

Comment: This isn't common at all for a logo. A company needs to own a logo outright. Any half decent graphic designer understands that.

Comment: I'm not saying it is a good system, but it is a popular option for many designers because it demands return business... And there are plenty of people out there less than half decent taking design work @da01

Comment: I think you may be thinking about the common practice of designers retaining the work files for general design work. But not with logos, which have to be given to the client most of the time for them to manage as they see fit.

Comment: Nah, there are some that'll hold the files for ransom... But they were probably businesss majors or lawyers before, so you're probably screwed either way if you signed a contract with them lol @da01